# Oracle Select Query with row limit

Tags: java, oracle, sqlexception

This is my Oracle query

```
select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP TOP 150;
```

and below is the exception

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

Comment: oracle use other methods to fullfill top

Comment: select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP where rownum  < 150 ; this should work..Limit doesnot work with select in oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle:**

```
select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP WHERE ROWNUM <= 150
```

**MySQL:**

```
select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP LIMIT 150
```

**SQL Server / MS Access Syntax**

```
select TOP 150 TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP
```

Answer (score 0):

using ROWNUM:

```
 select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP WHERE ROWNUM <=150
```

Comment: getSampleData Mysql select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP LIMIT 10;
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: do not give semicolon and try

Comment: select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP WHERE ROWNUM <=150

Works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `TOP` correct query would be : **For SQL Server / MS Access**

```
select TOP 150 TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP;
```

Other options : **For Oracle and MySql**

```
SELECT TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP WHERE ROWNUM <=150;
```

Comment: This is for SQL server.

Comment: select TOPIC,SEQ,INFO FROM HELP WHERE ROWNUM <=150

Works fine. THx a lot